# Performance variance among string-compare methods

Tags: python, string, string-comparison

As a student, I have a course about using new features in Python3.8+ and it also includes Python3.10. So I'm now trying to use match-case in my homework to kill a long series of if-else which should be replace by switch-case in cpp.

In my homework I need a function to convert string "male/female/..." into integer. It's quite easy but I was suddenly interested in the performace of different string-compare methods so I designed the testing code below to test the performance among three different methods.

```
import timeit
from typing import Callable


def test_match_case(sex: str):
    match sex:
        case 'male':
            gender = 1
        case 'female':
            gender = 2
        case '________female':
            gender = 3
        case '#________________female':
            gender = 4
        case _:
            gender = 0

    return gender


def test_if_full_compare(sex: str):
    if sex == 'male':
        gender = 1
    elif sex == 'female':
        gender = 2
    elif sex == '________female':
        gender = 3
    elif sex == '#________________female':
        gender = 4
    else:
        gender = 0

    return gender


def test_if_startswith(sex: str):
    if sex.startswith('m'):
        gender = 1
    elif sex.startswith('f'):
        gender = 2
    elif sex.startswith('_'):
        gender = 3
    elif sex.startswith('#'):
        gender = 4
    else:
        gender = 0

    return gender


def _test_and_print(func: Callable, arg: str, times: int = 10000000):
    func_name = func.__name__
    time_cost = timeit.timeit(f"""{func_name}("{arg}")""", f"""from __main__ import {func_name}""", number=times)
    print(f"func: {func_name} arg: {arg} time_cost: {time_cost:.6f}")


_test_and_print(test_match_case, "male")
_test_and_print(test_match_case, "female")
_test_and_print(test_match_case, "________female")
_test_and_print(test_match_case, "#________________female")
_test_and_print(test_if_full_compare, "male")
_test_and_print(test_if_full_compare, "female")
_test_and_print(test_if_full_compare, "________female")
_test_and_print(test_if_full_compare, "#________________female")
_test_and_print(test_if_startswith, "male")
_test_and_print(test_if_startswith, "female")
_test_and_print(test_if_startswith, "________female")
_test_and_print(test_if_startswith, "#________________female")
```

Here is the testing result on my PC:

```
func: test_match_case arg: male time_cost: 0.517885
func: test_match_case arg: female time_cost: 0.610869
func: test_match_case arg: ________female time_cost: 0.726382
func: test_match_case arg: #________________female time_cost: 0.846604
func: test_if_full_compare arg: male time_cost: 0.487761
func: test_if_full_compare arg: female time_cost: 0.578670
func: test_if_full_compare arg: ________female time_cost: 0.666413
func: test_if_full_compare arg: #________________female time_cost: 0.827917
func: test_if_startswith arg: male time_cost: 0.917373
func: test_if_startswith arg: female time_cost: 1.362152
func: test_if_startswith arg: ________female time_cost: 1.817514
func: test_if_startswith arg: #________________female time_cost: 2.249916
```

I have learned a little about "Resident Memory" in Python, but I still have tons of questions about the result above.

1. match-case is slower than if-else in every case, why?
2. The time-cost gap between L4 and L8 is much smaller than the other three cases (L1-L5, L2-L6, L3-L7), why? Is this effected by "Resident Memory"?
3. startswith has such terrible speed with long string. In my gut this build-in function only needs to compare the first character so the time-cost of the last 4 cases should be nearly the same and L12 should be much faster than L8 since it don't need to traverse the entire string. But the truth is the exact opposite of my estimation. How to explain this?
4. If you find out any other question, please tell me.

I've already searched with words "[python] string compare" but didn't get any expected result.

Comment: `match` isn't available until Python 3.10, I'm unable to try it in Python 3.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's three reasons for your performance issues, the first two essentially the language/interpreter's "fault", the other one a consequence of how you constructed your test cases:

1. Python is not a fully compiled, statically typed language, and this means `match` can't typically optimize much (if I recall correctly, it might even be required to consider `case`s in order, making it even harder to optimize), and in practice, never performs meaningful optimizations for "jumping" to the right `case`. The `match` construct's design actually adds a tiny amount of overhead over `if`/`elif`/`else` chains here, but it's otherwise *equivalent* to the `if`/`elif`/`else` chain, making it slightly slower in most cases (see details below; there's a reason it catches up on the final case).
2. Generalized code paths without dedicated bytecode support (e.g. arbitrary method calls) typically have higher fixed overhead than bytecode supported operations (e.g. direct `==` checks), so if the work done is the same, the bytecode operation wins. They've been improving this over time with `LOAD_METHOD`/`CALL_METHOD` opcodes that avoid creating bound method objects, and the Vectorcall protocol to reduce argument handling overhead, but a dedicated bytecode still wins in most cases, so if `==` and `startswith` do the same real work, `==` will win.
3. Even theoretically, `startswith` doesn't save anything *in this particular use case*; every one of your fixed strings is of a different length, so the actual equality test starts off with "do the lengths match?", finds they don't, and immediately says "not equal"; it never even reads a single byte of the string data when they're not equal. And when they are equal, odds are since three of the four strings involved are literals containing legal variable names (which CPython interns as an implementation detail), isn't not even comparing the string's data in the case where they're equal; it checks the "is interned" bit, finds its set in both, and knowing that, can compare the pointer addresses (it might even do this before the size check); two interned strings are equal if and only if they are the *same* string, so again, no data comparisons required.

---

**Details on point #1/question #2**: I checked the results of calling `dis.dis` on two identical functions, one of which used `match`/`case` and one of which used `if`/`elif`/`else` chains. The bytecode produced by CPython 3.10.0 is *almost* identical, except:

1. The `match`/`case` chain loads the string only once, then before each test save the last one, it uses the `DUP_TOP` instruction to double the value on the top of the stack (just double the reference, no copies made) so the new copy can be used for the comparison, and the original one sticks around for the next comparison. The `DUP_TOP` is a super-cheap instruction (roughly equivalent to the `LOAD_FAST` it uses in the `if` chain where you have to name the local variable over and over), but...
2. Since any *successful* comparison means the duplicate value isn't needed, all paths save the final one need to add a `POP_TOP` instruction to clear the duplicate that the `if`/`elif` chain doesn't need.

**This explains your observation in question #2**; all the code paths that end with a `case` that involves a `DUP_TOP` execute one extra bytecode instruction (the corresponding `POP_TOP`), while the final case doesn't need it so the instructions executed end up being roughly the same (it executes one `LOAD_FAST` and *case count* `DUP_TOP`s, rather than *case count* `LOAD_FAST`s); `DUP_TOP` being *very* slightly cheaper than `LOAD_FAST` (but not nearly enough to make up the cost of a `POP_TOP` when it's needed), you perform *slightly* better on the final `case` of the `match` that uses the value being matched.

Comment: I didn't specifically address question #2, but odds are it's either a timing artifact (using `timeit.repeat` and taking the best time of 5 or 7 is usually a good way to minimize these) or it's related in some way to `'#________________female'` being the only string among your constants being compared which *isn't* automatically interned by Python (due to the `#` in it, which can't be part of a legal variable name).

Comment: I've learned a lot through your answer, thanks!

Comment: @Starry-OvO: You're welcome. I figured out your question #2 by the way; it's an artifact of how `match` handles the fact that it only loads the value to be compared once, then uses instructions that duplicate the top of the stack to reuse it over and over. That's a good thing when the value is expensive to load/compute (e.g. using `self.someattr` over and over in an `if`/`elif` chain involves a more-expensive-than-you'd-think attribute load for each test that `match self.someattr:` only pays once), but it means it has to execute 1-2 additional instructions. See the updated answer for details.

Comment: I completely understand the details. It's a wonderful answer

Answer (score 0):

You missed what I think would be the most pythonic solution, using a dictionary.  I expected it to be the fastest for every case, but it's not.  The cascading `elif` clauses are going to be slower the farther down the list you go, because it has to fail each preceding test before it moves to the next.

```
_sex_dict = {
    'male':                   1,
    'female':                 2,
    '________female':         3,
    '#________________female':4
    }

def test_dict(sex: str):
    gender = _sex_dict.get(sex, 0)
    return gender
```

```
func: test_if_full_compare arg: male time_cost: 1.621118
func: test_if_full_compare arg: female time_cost: 1.786827
func: test_if_full_compare arg: ________female time_cost: 2.041604
func: test_if_full_compare arg: #________________female time_cost: 2.434724
func: test_if_startswith arg: male time_cost: 2.886888
func: test_if_startswith arg: female time_cost: 4.518326
func: test_if_startswith arg: ________female time_cost: 5.808293
func: test_if_startswith arg: #________________female time_cost: 7.220475
func: test_dict arg: male time_cost: 1.917939
func: test_dict arg: female time_cost: 1.924376
func: test_dict arg: ________female time_cost: 1.930555
func: test_dict arg: #________________female time_cost: 2.079617
```

Comment: This O(1) method may work with more cases to be compared, maybe 5 or more. Thanks for your testing!

Comment: Stupid Python optimization tricks. Change the function to `def test_dict(sex: str, *, _sex_get=_sex_dict.get): return _sex_get(sex, 0)` and you'll replace a `LOAD_GLOBAL`+`LOAD_METHOD`+`CALL_METHOD` with `LOAD_FAST`+`CALL_FUNCTION` (not as important now that there's per-opcode `LOAD_GLOBAL` caches and `LOAD_METHOD`/`CALL_METHOD` avoid making a bound method, but it helped more on older Python), and by not assigning to a variable that you just immediately load for `return`, you skip an unnecessary `LOAD_FAST`/`STORE_FAST` combo. Saves about 5-10%, making the `dict` win quicker.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks for the optimization strategy, but when I tried it on my system I didn't see any improvement in the run times - any difference was within the margin of error and not consistent.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Yeah, locally, the prebound default argument strategy component didn't actually do anything noticeable on 3.10 (like I said, it mattered more on older Python). Saving the `STORE_FAST`/`LOAD_FAST` two-fer definitionally saves something, but it's not going to be huge (both instructions typically execute in single digit ns).